# Reading Eclipse Status Line

Tags: eclipse, line, status, rcp

I'm building an Eclipse RCP application and setting text in the shared status line via:

```
IStatusLineManager statusLine = 
    getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getStatusLineManager();

statusLine.setMessage("some status text");
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to read back the current text displayed in the shared status line? I notice you can do so with StatusLineContributionItem's but doesn't seem so with the shared status line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nasty way:
Relies on the implementation of the StatusLine class not changing - so proceed with caution:

StatusLineManager.getControl() returns a StatusLine (which is package protected), however it subclasses composite, which means you can call getChildren(), and one of these children will be a CLabel containing the message.

This is horrendously hacky though.

Nicer way, but more work:

From the documentation of StatusLineManager it says that clients may subclass to provide different layouts, so presumably you could subclass this and provide a means of exposing the last status message.

If you are building an RCP you should be subclassing WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, which has a constructor:

```
  public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) ...
```

From the constuctor you could call:

```
   configurer.setPresentationFactory(factory);
```

Note, from my javadocs:

```
   Deprecated. the presentation factory is now obtained via extension point and a preference on org.eclipse.ui specifying which one to use; see IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.PRESENTATION_FACTORY_ID
```

So you may want to investigate that extension point instead.

the factory object should be your own subclass of AbstractPresentationFactory (or indeed WorkbenchPresentationFactory),
overriding this method:

```
  public IStatusLineManager createStatusLineManager() {
    return new StatusLineManager();
}
```

to return your own subclass of StatusLineManager.

NOTE: I'm using Eclipse 3.4.2, so double check the docs for the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is bad practice to read from UI. Eclipse architecture is MVC and that means your status should be saved in controller if you need it for later purpose.

If I were you, I would store the status using extension points:

- **org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables**, or
- **org.eclipse.core.variables.valueVariables**

I will change the value of the variable instead of changing the status line directly and use [IValueVariableListener](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/variables/IValueVariableListener.html) to (automatically) update the status line.